# How to patch AssemblyInfo in TeamCity for .net core 2.1 projects?

Tags: teamcity

In the .net core 2.1 project, there is a `*.csproj` file, that contains assembly information:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyVersion>2019.1.15341.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>2019.1.15341.0</FileVersion>
    <Version>2019.1.15341</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In Standard **.net** projects there were Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs which contained the Assembly information, but in the .net core, there is no AssemblyInfo.cs, all Assembly information are in the csproj.

How can I change the Assembly Version, File Version in Assembly Info ***Patcher*** in ***TeamCity*** for the **.net** core projects?

Comment: Are you using the dotnet runner to build the project in Team City, if yes then just pass the /p:Version as a command line param and that should version the output libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `File Content Replacer` build feature with predefined templates for .NET Core

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/file-content-replacer.html#.NET+Core+csproj+templates

Comment: Please see this answer for how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51190626/894792

Answer (score 2):

Using `/p` switch didn't work for my. However `-p` works just fine

```
dotnet build -p:Version=1.2.3.4
```

You can also apply the same switch to the dotnet pack

```
dotnet pack Yourproject.csproj -p:Version=1.2.3.4
```

look at this page https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#msbuild for details.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone misses it, Rajesh commented above that *if using the .NET CLI Runner* you can simply add this to the **Command line parameters** option for the build step:

```
/p:Version=%build.number%
```

..and it'll version all the binaries for you.  This worked for me and seems simpler than configuring the `File Content Replacer` as above.

I've added this as it seems to be a perfectly acceptable answer, and because Rajesh's comment didn't give full details (pointed me in the right direction though)

Comment: Wow great! This is simple. Will try in next project. Till then can you provide documentation for it ?